# Name for a categorical adjunction that is a "semi-equivalence"

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology

Is there a name for an adjunction between two categories such that

i) the unit of the adjunction is a natural isomorphism,

ii) the counit of the adjunction is a natural isomorphism?

Comment: Colocalization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An adjunction for which the unit is a natural isomorphism is called a [coreflective adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coreflective+subcategory). An adjunction for which the counit is a natural isomorphism is called a [reflective adjunction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory).

Comment: In particular, see “Proposition 3.1. (equivalent characterizations)” on the [nlab page for reflective subcategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory) that varkor linked — item (2) of that is the counit being iso.